# Can you calculate the average distance between a set of shapes in shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

For a set of N polygons. What is the fasters way to calculate the average across all shapes and their nearest neighbour. Where the nearest neighbour is shape which has a point nearest to a point on the current shape closer than any other.

Comment: So, you are not looking for the center-to-center distance, but instead you are looking for the closest points on the perimeter?  That's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using geopandas, you could use [sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest).

The following code snippet gives an idea how this could work. It lists for each NY borough which are the closest other boroughs (all having the same distance are listed):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

countries_gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("nybb"))

result_gdf = None
for row in countries_gdf.itertuples():
    cur_country_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([row], crs=countries_gdf.crs)
    other_countries_gdf = countries_gdf[countries_gdf.index != row.Index]
    nearest_other_gdf = cur_country_gdf.sjoin_nearest(
        other_countries_gdf, distance_col="distance"
    )
    if result_gdf is None:
        result_gdf = nearest_other_gdf
    else:
        result_gdf = pd.concat([result_gdf, nearest_other_gdf])

print(
result_gdf[["BoroName_left", "BoroName_right", "distance"]].to_string(index=False))
```

Result:

```
BoroName_left BoroName_right    distance
Staten Island       Brooklyn 4895.344637
       Queens       Brooklyn    0.000000
       Queens      Manhattan    0.000000
       Queens          Bronx    0.000000
     Brooklyn         Queens    0.000000
     Brooklyn      Manhattan    0.000000
    Manhattan       Brooklyn    0.000000
    Manhattan         Queens    0.000000
    Manhattan          Bronx    0.000000
        Bronx         Queens    0.000000
        Bronx      Manhattan    0.000000
```